# How to properly wait to check if an Excel instance has closed after attempting to?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, win32com, pythoncom

I'm using the [Python standard library modules](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html) and the `pythoncom` and `win32com.client` modules from the `PyWin32` package to interact with Microsoft Excel.

I get a list of the running Excel instances as COM object references and then when I want to close the Excel instances I first iterate through the workbooks and close them. Then I execute the [Quit method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.quit) and after I attempt to terminate the Excel process if it's not terminated.

I do the check (`_is_process_running`) because the Excel instance might not close successfully if for example the Excel process is a zombie process ([information on how one can be created](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/55)) or if the VBA listens to the [before close event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforeclose) and cancels it.

My current quirky solution to know when to check if it closed is to use the [sleep function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep). It does seem to work but it can fail in certain circumstances, such as if it takes longer than the sleep function waits for.

I thought that clearing all the COM references and collecting the garbage would be enough for the Excel process to terminate if the `Quit` method does succeed but it still takes some time asynchronously.

The check is in the `close` method of the `_excel_application_wrapper` class in the `excel.pyw` file.

---

Simple code to generate an Excel zombie process (you can see the process in the task manager):

```
from os import getpid, kill
from win32com.client import DispatchEx

_ = DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
kill(getpid(), 9)
```

This is only for testing purposes to help reproduce an Excel instance that won't be closed when calling `Quit`.

Another way to make `Quit` fail to close is to add this VBA code to the workbook in Excel:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
  Cancel = True
End Sub
```

---

Code on the `excel_test.py` file:

```
import excel
from traceback import print_exc as print_exception

try:
  excel_application_instances = excel.get_application_instances()
  for excel_application_instance in excel_application_instances:
    # use excel_application_instance here before closing it
    # ...
    excel_application_instance.close()
except Exception:
  print('An exception has occurred. Details of the exception:')
  print_exception()
finally:
  input('Execution finished.')
```

Code on the `excel.pyw` file:

```
from ctypes import byref as by_reference, c_ulong as unsigned_long, windll as windows_dll
from gc import collect as collect_garbage
from pythoncom import CreateBindCtx as create_bind_context, GetRunningObjectTable as get_running_object_table, \
  IID_IDispatch as dispatch_interface_iid, _GetInterfaceCount as get_interface_count
from win32com.client import Dispatch as dispatch

class _object_wrapper_base_class():
  def __init__(self, object_to_be_wrapped):
    # self.__dict__['_wrapped_object'] instead of
    # self._wrapped_object to prevent recursive calling of __setattr__
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/12999019
    self.__dict__['_wrapped_object'] = object_to_be_wrapped
  def __getattr__(self, name):
    return getattr(self._wrapped_object, name)
  def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    setattr(self._wrapped_object, name, value)

class _excel_workbook_wrapper(_object_wrapper_base_class):
  # __setattr__ takes precedence over properties with setters
  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/15751159
  def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    # raises AttributeError if the attribute doesn't exist
    getattr(self, name)
    if name in vars(_excel_workbook_wrapper):
      attribute = vars(_excel_workbook_wrapper)[name]
      # checks if the attribute is a property with a setter
      if isinstance(attribute, property) and attribute.fset is not None:
        attribute.fset(self, value)
        return
    setattr(self._wrapped_object, name, value)
  @property
  def saved(self):
    return self.Saved
  @saved.setter
  def saved(self, value):
    self.Saved = value
  def close(self):
    self.Close()

class _excel_workbooks_wrapper(_object_wrapper_base_class):
  def __getitem__(self, key):
    return _excel_workbook_wrapper(self._wrapped_object[key])

class _excel_application_wrapper(_object_wrapper_base_class):
  @property
  def workbooks(self):
    return _excel_workbooks_wrapper(self.Workbooks)
  def _get_process(self):
    window_handle = self.hWnd
    process_identifier = unsigned_long()
    windows_dll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(window_handle, by_reference(process_identifier))
    return process_identifier.value
  def _is_process_running(self, process_identifier):
    SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000
    process_handle = windows_dll.kernel32.OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, False, process_identifier)
    returned_value = windows_dll.kernel32.WaitForSingleObject(process_handle, 0)
    windows_dll.kernel32.CloseHandle(process_handle)
    WAIT_TIMEOUT = 0x00000102
    return returned_value == WAIT_TIMEOUT
  def _terminate_process(self, process_identifier):
    PROCESS_TERMINATE = 0x0001
    process_handle = windows_dll.kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, False, process_identifier)
    process_terminated = windows_dll.kernel32.TerminateProcess(process_handle, 0)
    windows_dll.kernel32.CloseHandle(process_handle)
    return process_terminated != 0
  def close(self):
    for workbook in self.workbooks:
      workbook.saved = True
      workbook.close()
      del workbook
    process_identifier = self._get_process()
    self.Quit()
    del self._wrapped_object
    # 0 COM references
    print(f'{get_interface_count()} COM references.')
    collect_garbage()
    # quirky solution to wait for the Excel process to
    # terminate if it did closed successfully from self.Quit()
    windows_dll.kernel32.Sleep(1000)
    # check if the Excel instance closed successfully
    # it may not close for example if the Excel process is a zombie process
    # or if the VBA listens to the before close event and cancels it
    if self._is_process_running(process_identifier=process_identifier):
      print('Excel instance failed to close.')
      # if the process is still running then attempt to terminate it
      if self._terminate_process(process_identifier=process_identifier):
        print('The process of the Excel instance was successfully terminated.')
      else:
        print('The process of the Excel instance failed to be terminated.')
    else:
      print('Excel instance closed successfully.')

def get_application_instances():
  running_object_table = get_running_object_table()
  bind_context = create_bind_context()
  excel_application_class_clsid = '{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}'
  excel_application_clsid = '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}'
  excel_application_instances = []
  for moniker in running_object_table:
    display_name = moniker.GetDisplayName(bind_context, None)
    if excel_application_class_clsid not in display_name:
      continue
    unknown_com_interface = running_object_table.GetObject(moniker)
    dispatch_interface = unknown_com_interface.QueryInterface(dispatch_interface_iid)
    dispatch_clsid = str(dispatch_interface.GetTypeInfo().GetTypeAttr().iid)
    if dispatch_clsid != excel_application_clsid:
      continue
    excel_application_instance_com_object = dispatch(dispatch=dispatch_interface)
    excel_application_instance = _excel_application_wrapper(excel_application_instance_com_object)
    excel_application_instances.append(excel_application_instance)
  return excel_application_instances
```

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32717130) suggests checking if the remote procedural call (RPC) server is unavailable by calling something from the COM object. I have tried trial and error in different ways without success. Such as adding the code below after `self.Quit()`.

```
from pythoncom import com_error, CoUninitialize as co_uninitialize
from traceback import print_exc as print_exception

co_uninitialize()
try:
  print(self._wrapped_object)
except com_error as exception:
  if exception.hresult == -2147023174: # "The RPC server is unavailable."
    print_exception()
  else:
    raise
```

Comment: So what is your problem? 1) You have some cases where there are Excel running processes and you do not detect them, or 2) You can identify all Excel running processes 100% correctly but you do not know how to kill all of them.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio The second option is close to it. I can identify all the running Excel instances. And I can terminate any of the processes. It's just that I only want to do that as a last resource in case terminating it correctly with Excel's `Quit()` method doesn't work.

Comment: I still do not understand what objective you mean to accomplish, which you cannot.
Would that be "Making sure that the only way to exit an Excel process is by killing it"?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio No. My current solution does the following: iterate through each instance running, do whatever I want with them, and then when I want to close them I first do [`Quit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.quit) which usually closes it. Except that in some rare cases it doesn't, as in the examples given. So it checks (the process of the instance) after some time (1 second) to see if it did closed. If it did then continue, else it forces it to close by terminating the process. My question is about the waiting 1 second part.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio Because it can take less or more than the 1 second to close from the `Quit` method. A proper solution would be to detect when `Quit` finishes and check then if it did worked (closed) or not. Since if `Quit` takes less than 1 second then the Python code is needlessly waiting for the full second, and if it takes longer then the code terminates the process while the `Quit` method has not finished running. (I think `Quit` is synchronous, the problem is that it returns no value about if it worked or not and before the instance's process is closed if it did worked).

Comment: So you want to detect when `Quit` finished, regardless of the time it takes?
And perhaps set a *maximum* waiting time, after which you would do something else (like asking whether to kill the process)?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio Yes. I already found half of the answer, just haven't updated the question with it. In the method `_is_process_running` of the `_excel_application_wrapper` class, I can change the value of `WaitForSingleObject` from `0` to `1000` and remove the use of the `Sleep` function. That way, it does the same as before except that if the `Quit` method does work and closes the process before the second ends, it gets detected right away. (so instead of waiting 1 second and then checking the process, it checks the process and only waits 1 second if the process is running)

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio So what I need to have it working exactly as I want it to, is to detect faster if `Quit` doesn't work. Instead of waiting a second or some other arbitrary amount of time, I want to know if it failed or not after being executed (checking the process right after `Quit` is executed doesn't work because the Excel process might have just not been closed yet even if `Quit` worked and the visible window of the Excel application is closed).

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio I don't know if you have Excel and Python but if you do you should be able to test it yourself and understand it better with the help of my explanation.

Comment: Ok, so I have two comments... 1) It is best if you update/reorganize the OP so it is clearer, it will help others help you (and spend time on the actual problem), 2) You could now simply split the waiting in nested loops, with the first checking being at, say, 10 milliseconds.
AFAIK, there is no way to detect an event as you mean to. And in that case, 
I guess your code will be more "elegant", but you won't get any better performance than with the proposal above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object_name.close`, which returns False if the file is not properly closed.

Using your code:

```
def close(self):
  for workbook in self.workbooks:
    workbook.saved = True
    workbook.close()
    if workbook.closed:
        del workbook
    else:
        print("Lookout, it's a zombie! Workbook was not deleted")
```

However, I should also mention that [Pep 343](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html) has an even better solution using Python's `with` context manager. This will ensure the file is closed before further execution.

Example:

```
with open("file_name", "w") as openfile:
    # do some work

# "file_name" is now closed
```

Comment: Closing all the workbooks does not close the Excel application instance. `workbook` is an object of the class `excel._excel_workbook_wrapper` and does not has the attribute `closed` (`print(hasattr(workbook, 'closed'))` prints `False`). Using `with` also does not help in my situation. I think you might have confused the question or just didn't tested your solution attempt.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the you know how to detect the current state of Excel instances.
The only point you are missing is detecting an event for the `Quit`ting action.

AFAIK, there is no way to detect an event as you mean to.
But a (possibly very good) workaround is setting time points, e.g. in a list, and check the status at those points.
If you are concerned about wasting 1000ms, and at the same time performing an excessive number of checks, you could set your list as [1, 3, 10, 30, ...], i.e., equispaced in log(time).

Even if there is an event available, I guess your code would be more "elegant", but you won't get any better performance than with the proposal above (unless the wait time is in the range of, say, minutes or above).